# how to redraw the series of point in bubble chart after some delay using achartengine?

Tags: java, achartengine

I'm having following code 
here i'm clearing the first `graph` view which is plotted after 2 sec delay and calling method to redraw buts its not drawing

```
        paint=true;
        while(paint)
        {
        //for(int s=0;s<4;s++){
        new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {          
            @Override
            public void run() {
                //this code will be executed after 2 seconds      
                // HRChartView.repaint();
                // addSeriesValues(false);                  
                series.clearSeriesValues();
                HRChartView.repaint();
                HRChartView.refreshDrawableState();
                System.out.println("repaintttttt");
              }
        }, 2000);
        paint=false;
        }
        //paint=false;
        // function contains xy series values
        addSeriesValues(false);



private void addSeriesValues(boolean trfalvalue) {
series = new XYValueSeries("");

series.add(24f, 34, 5);
series.remove(0);


series.add(26f, 41, 2);

series.add(27f, 40, 3);
series.add(26.02f, 44.2, 4);
series.add(28.03f, 41.3, 5);
series.add(26.04f, 41.4, 8);
series.add(24.05f, 41.5, 8);
series.add(25.06f, 42.6, 8);
series.add(28.07f, 45.7, 8);
series.add(26.08f, 41.8, 8);
series.add(27.09f, 49.9, 8);
//trfalvalue=true;

if (trfalvalue) { 

    series.remove(9);

    series.add(genRandom(21,30), genRandom(31, 35));


}
}
```

Comment: im clearing the first graph view which is plotted after 2 sec delay and calling method to redraw buts its not drawing

Comment: @SindhuBC any excpetions or errors

Comment: no exception or error...Raghunandan

Answer (score 0):

You clear the `series` and then you add nothing back, so it is no surprise that there is nothing to display.

Comment: So how would the OP redraw the series?

Comment: The next line after he clears the series is a repaint which does what its name suggests.